# Calling a google script function in html page

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a function in Google Script Editor that appends a row in Google Spreadsheet. Values being passed as parameters.
Now, what I want to do is, call this function in my HTML page (built using UI Services, not HTML Services) and pass the values to be stored from this page. I cannot find a way. Pls help?

Answer (score 0):

At the time you asked this question, the documentation was not very rich. It has improved considerably, and there are examples provided that are close to what you want to do.

With the [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp), the way you would accomplish this would be by using a handler function, either [client-side](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#ClientHandlers) or [server-side](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#ServerHandlers), which would be triggered by a button click (for example), and handle the submission of a "form" (a set of input text areas, etc.). The handler would call your storage function, passing the values returned from the form.

See the examples in the documentation links provided above.

If your web app used Html Services, you would have several options for calling server-side apps-script, see [Html Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication). There are also numerous questions here that demonstrate this:

- [Call a Google Apps Script function in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867291/call-a-google-apps-script-function-in-html)
- [HtmlService form submit opens new tab with foo bar URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597301/gas-spreadsheets-htmlservice-form-submit-opens-new-tab-with-foo-bar-url)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

`google.script.run.nameOfYourFunction();`

Use this to call your function that is defined outside of the html file, from within the html file. Based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)