# Google Script - How to write text to screen at start of script processing

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that I need to output text to the screen.

I know this can be accomplished with

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("blah blah");
```

But I need to have text written to the screen as soon as my script starts processing not when it returns...

How can can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what services your script is using, and what container (if any) houses it. In a spreadsheet, for instance, you could pop up a "toast" message. However, it appears that you're using HtmlService, most likely as a deployed web app.

One option would be to replace the text content of an element on the html page. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497828/1677912) for an example of that.